# How to Fix ComplexPlot3D from MathWorld Notebook on Bessel Functions of the First Kind

Tags: complexplot3d

In trying to understand Bessel Functions, I opened a Wolfram notebook (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html)

However, when I attempt to evaluate the following expression:

```
ComplexPlot3D[BesselJ[0, z], {z, -5, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100] // Timing
```

I get a timing but no plot together with a warning
"ComplexPlot3D::plld: Corners for z in {z,-5,5} must have distinct machine-precision real and imaginary parts."

**Is there a way to generate the plot?**

I am running Vers. 14.0 on a Windows 11 64bit platform.

Comment: `ComplexPlot3D[BesselJ[0, z], {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, PlotPoints -> 100] // Timing`

Comment: That makes sense and works, but I'm not sure why the second expression in the notebook does not:   ComplexContourPlot[BesselJ[0, z], {z, -5 + 5  I, 5 - 5  I}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100] // Timing

Comment: From the documentation, "At positions where f does not evaluate to a real number, holes are left so that the background to the contour plot shows through." Use `(ComplexContourPlot[#@BesselJ[0, z], {z, -5 + 5  I, 5 - 5  I}, 
     PlotPoints -> 100] // Timing) & /@ {Abs, Re, Im}`

Comment: That worked.  Thanks